# Angular JS: pass scope data to JSON

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs, angularjs-scope

Hello how can I pass `$scope` data to JSON when I initialise it?

e.g I have scope `users`:

```
$scope.users = [
  { name: "Camila Gilson" },
  { name: "Chloe Creighton" },
  { name: "Zoey White" }
];
```

I want to store users's info in json, is it possible?

Thanks?

Comment: JSON.stringify($scope.users)

Comment: What do you mean by store the user's info?  Store it where?

Answer (score 3):

Yes, this is what `toJson` and `fromJson` are for

```
angular.toJson($scope.users);
```

Will result in a string with JSON format and

```
angular.fromJson(yourJsonString);
```

Will convert it back.